# If I have cast the Fire Shield spell, and then I cast True Polymorph on myself, what happens to the fire shield?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, polymorph

If I cast Fire Shield, and afterwards cast True Polymorph, does the new form still have fire shield protection?

Comment: I've edited the secondary question about *armor of Agathys* out of your post. You may want to ask it separately instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Yes, your new form would still have *Fire Shield* on it.

Assuming you're casting *True Polymorph* on yourself, nothing in the [*Fire Shield*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/fire-shield) spell description indicates it would stop working if you were to change form. The range is 'Self', not 'The current version of Self'.

Also, *Fire Shield* isn't a concentration spell, and so it would not be canceled by casting a concentration spell like [*True Polymorph*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/true-polymorph). Finally, even though *True Polymorph* says:

> The creature can't activate, use, wield, or otherwise benefit from any
> of its equipment.

*Fire Shield* is not equipment, nor is it being activated/wielded/etc.